# PHP $_Session variable not recognised

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to differentiate between an admin user and a client with the session variable. Depending on their user type, they will be shown different content of the page. In order to do that, I wanted to check the user's type in the database depending on the $_SESSION after login.
It's not an ideal solution but the simplest I can think of, yet I still can't get this to work.
Database table holding user details is called LS_Users and the field storing user type (values: either "A" for admin or "C" for client) is called userType.

The problem I'm having is that the user type is not being picked up properly.

The code below doesn't read the user type.

```
$usertype = isset($_POST['userType']) ? $_POST['userType'] : $_SESSION['userType'];
$usertype=$_POST['user_type'];
 $thisuserSQL="select * from LS_Users where  userType = '".$usertype."'";
 $exethisuserSQL=mysql_query($thisuserSQL) or die (mysql_error());
 $userArray=mysql_fetch_array($exethisuserSQL);
 if ($userArray['userType']!=$usertype)
 {
  echo "Usertype: ".$_SESSION['userType'];
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Usertype: empty";
 }

And the code below returns the first value from the database instead of matching it to the actual user that logged in.
if ($_SESSION['c_userid'])
{
 echo "Name: ".$_SESSION['c_fname'].", Id: ".$_SESSION['c_userid'], "Usertype: ".$_SESSION['userType'];
 echo "<hr>";
 $usertype = $_REQUEST['userType'];
 $currentuserSQL="select * from LS_Users";
// where userType =" '$usertype';
 $execurrentuserSQL=mysql_query($currentuserSQL) or die (mysql_error());
 $userArray=mysql_fetch_array($execurrentuserSQL);
$_SESSION['c_userid']=$userArray['user_id'];
 $_SESSION['userType']=$userArray['userType'];

 echo "<p>Hello, ".$_SESSION['c_fname']."! ";

 if ($_SESSION['userType']== "C")
  {
  echo "<p>Client";
  }
 elseif ($_SESSION['userType']== "A")
  {
  echo "<p>Admin";
  }
 else
 {
  echo "<p>Empty";
  }
}
else
{
 echo "Please log in.";
}
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Have you already started the session with session_start() ?

Comment: you are calling `session_start()` somewhere before this code is executed, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's already in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the magical `session_start();` function into your code?

Put it in the very beginning of every file which uses sessions:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  ...
```

Comment: It magically fixes many problems like this. I've pulled hair when my application didn't work, only to find that I didn't put this thing into the code. That's why I use Python now ;)

Comment: Yes, I did, and the connection to the database too

Comment: Hmm, what error are you getting? I can't do much if you just say that it doesn't work.

Comment: I doubt Python you will do any help for you if you had problems like this

Comment: There's no errors. First code returns Usertype:empty, which is the else option from the if statement. Second code returns "A" every time, even for the client user, because it's the first entry in the user table.

Comment: Hmm, it looks fine to me. Just an FYI, this is just waiting to be SQL injected: `$thisuserSQL="select * from LS_Users where  userType = '".$usertype."'";`

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "waiting to be SQL injected"? I thought the if statement was calling the session variable from the sql statement?

Comment: `where userType = '".$usertype."'";` is inserting `$usertype` directly into the SQL string. What if I supplied `$usertype = "' or 1=1;"`. This is true, since `1=1` is evaluated, so I just passed myself off as an admin.

Comment: @Lucy It's a rather long read, but [this article on SQL injection attacks](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) explains the topic clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem only happens for the `userType`, I would like to verify that your php configuration does not have the `register_globals` activated. If it does, it might be the source of your problems. Otherwise, please answer the following questions:

Are you sure the other session variables are working?
Are you sure the initialization of the `$_SESSION['userType']` is working?
Can you write it after having initialized it?

Comment: @Lucy Does the register_globals is set to off? (check php.ini)